# Orbot Netcipher connecting to .onion urls

Tags: java, android, proxy, tor, orbot

So, I'm trying to get my app to work with .onion domains, but all I get is a 405 error for a response. I have tried everything, my code seems to work when I try `http://check.torproject.org` it says that its connected.

https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher

My gradle contains these dependencies.

```
compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:2.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher-okhttp3:2.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```

I'm running this code to start orbot and connect the app to it.

```
OrbotHelper.get(activity).statusTimeout(60000).addStatusCallback(new StatusCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Intent intent){
        new StrongBuild();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStarting(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopping(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusTimeout(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotYetInstalled(){
    }
}).init();
```

This is the StrongBuild file.

```
import android.util.Log;

import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import info.guardianproject.netcipher.client.StrongBuilder;
import info.guardianproject.netcipher.client.StrongOkHttpClientBuilder;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class StrongBuild implements StrongBuilder.Callback<OkHttpClient> {

public StrongBuild(){
    Log.e("info", "Starting Strong Builder");
    try{
        StrongOkHttpClientBuilder.
                forMaxSecurity(activity).
                //withTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new MyTrustManager() }).
                withTorValidation().
                withBestProxy().
                build(StrongBuild.this);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("info", "ERROR");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(final OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
    Log.e("info" , "CONNECTED Strong Builder");

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://******.onion/").build();
                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                Log.e("info", "RESPONSE: "+response.toString());
                Log.e("info", response.body().string());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("info", "ERROR - ATTEMPTING CONNECTION TO ONION DOMAIN");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionException(Exception e){
    Log.e("info" , "Exception");
}

@Override
public void onTimeout(){
    Log.e("info" , "Timeout");
}

@Override
public void onInvalid(){
    Log.e("info" , "Invalid");
}
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
RESPONSE: Response{protocol=http/1.0, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=http://********.onion/}
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post your stacktrace

Comment: RESPONSE: Response{protocol=http/1.0, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=http://**********.onion/}

Comment: `Method Not Allowed,`

Comment: Exactly, why would a .onion domain not be allowed when im running a proxy through orbot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the issue, I'll post the answer for anyone else wondering!

Change this:

```
StrongOkHttpClientBuilder.
            forMaxSecurity(activity).
            //withTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new MyTrustManager() }).
            withTorValidation().
            withBestProxy().
            build(StrongBuild.this);
```

To this:

```
StrongOkHttpClientBuilder.
            forMaxSecurity(activity).
            withTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new MyTrustManager() }).
            withTorValidation().
            withSocksProxy().
            withHttpProxy().
            build(StrongBuild.this);
```